# css perfect full screen image background

Tags: css, image, fullscreen

I'm wondering which is the best solution for an background image to fit every screen, every browser. Also I've noticed that the majority of techniques crop the image a little bit.
I know there are a lot of techniques to do this but I want to know which is the best in your opinion.
Thanks!

Comment: I don't think there really is a catch all solution.  Your solution will greatly depend on what your image looks like and how it is being applied.  For example many background images leave a large gap the width of their content area in the center of the image.  While other background image show through the content area.  Some repeat.  There are several techniques for background images but they differ depending on the design.

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/3458-perfect-full-page-background-image/ - jquery method - probably best solution.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This [post from CSS-tricks.com](http://css-tricks.com/3458-perfect-full-page-background-image/) covers different techniques for full screen background images and includes a fall-back for old versions of IE (I haven't tested the IE fix).

When I don't need to worry about supporting old browsers, I generally use the CSS3 method:

```
html { 
    background: url(http://lorempixum.com/1440/900/sports)
        no-repeat center center fixed; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: Way old, I know, but is there a good alternate to this that won't resize with the browser? Wish I could give just the image a min-height

Answer (score 0):

Add this inside the body tag:

```
<img src="img/beach.jpg" 

style="width:100%;height:100%;position:absolute;top:0;left:0;z-index:-5000;">
```

http://thewebthought.blogspot.com/2010/10/css-making-background-image-fit-any.htmlg