# Full page image background

Tags: html, css

I've been trying to make my image display at full-size on the page, it works fine for my computer, but as soon as you zoom out to 25-50% in chrome the image doesn't follow up.

Here's a jsfiddle: `http://jsfiddle.net/97cn3c8x/`

And to be clear, I'm using this plugin I don't know how to include it in the jsfiddle though: http://matthew.wagerfield.com/parallax/

So feel free to zoom out your browser in the jsfiddle and you'll notice my problem. If the image would be in the css then `background-size: cover` would do the deal, but it doesn't seem to work for this.

Comment: impossible to get what you need since you limit it by fixed position

Comment: @JeanGkol oh really? I think Aljaz just did it in the answer below.

Comment: well, it is successfully solved then :D

Comment: why not just google first http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/ ? -1 for showing no research efforts :(

Comment: possible duplicate of [css perfect full screen image background](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7259084/css-perfect-full-screen-image-background)

Answer (score 0):

What I do to pin the image to all the corners of the screen is this:

```
.bgimg
       { 
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        background-size: cover;
        background-position: 50% 50%;
        }
```

Hope this helps and I answered your question. Good luck and keep coding ;)