# CSS Background Image full screen on mobile android devices not perfect

Tags: android, html, css, background-image

wow. How hard can it be to create a full screen background image with HTML and CSS?
Seems to be quite hard. At least, the internet if full of answers like this [css perfect full screen image background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7259084/css-perfect-full-screen-image-background) and this https://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/ .

In fact, the demo of the second link works also on mobile android devices: https://css-tricks.com/examples/FullPageBackgroundImage/progressive.php

But I still have no luck. I copied the style

```
html {
    background: url(/images/snowback.png) no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

To my stylesheet https://aoc-2019.netlify.com/css/retro.css and still, the background image is not perfect: https://aoc-2019.netlify.com

It first seems to be perfect, but the Android browser hides the adress bar when you scroll around a bit and then the background will not be resized. This leads to a region on hte bottom of the page which is not covered by the background image.

And as I said, the demo above works quite well.

What is the difference between my page and the demo? Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several differences on how the page is structured. Long story short, the main thing that is preventing it from working as you expected is the assignment of height: 100% to your HTML element. As you can read here [directly from Google's developers website](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/12/url-bar-resizing), assigning height: 100% gives to an element the height available with the bar displayed and won't resize once it's hidden.
If you don't want to revise and change your code and need a fast solution, just add height 110% to the HTML and you'll get the same effect as in the compared link.

Comment: awesome! Thanx for the reference to the google site.
So, what I didn't think of was the fact that I also have other style sheets applied. One has set the `body {height 100%;}` but it needs to be `auto` :-)

Answer (score 1):

The differences I can easily spot are...

CSS-Tricks version: html and body have no height or min-height.

Your version: html and body both set too 100% for height and min-height.

CSS-Tricks version: Body set to `overflow-x: hidden;`

Your version: No overflow rule on body.

I suggest you replicate what they did precisely, with no added content, make sure it works as expected. Then recreate it within your site.

If it turns out that the 100% height and min-height are the problem, and yet you need those for a sticky footer or something. Then you may be able to use a secondary wrapper div to facilitate your sticky footer. Like put the height/min-height rules on an fullwrapper div, then within that use a pagewrapper as normal with the sticky footer.

Comment: thanx.  it was the `height: 100%` which has to be `auto`!